# Regular Expression match only beginning of string

Tags: regex, syncback

I'm trying to match a regular expression on a string that has multiple matches, but i want to match the first occurrence and i'm expecting my match only in the beginning of the string

E.g.: `4_12052022_01.abc`

in the above `"4"` is my target for a match.

But my string can also have something like `1_231233_4_43.abc`, so here it should not match the occurrence of 4 because it's not in the beginning of the string.

I'm using SyncbackPro v9 and want to setup filtering through regex.

What i have tried and doesn't seem to work for me

`4_.*`, this matches both the strings above

`^4_.*`, this tests fine in most of the online regular testing websites, but in syncback it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you trying to match filenames inside all folders or inside particular folders? What's your specific use case and the regex filter you tried in SyncBackPro?

Comment: `^` is [said to be supported](https://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/help/expressionfilters.htm).